What is the difference between Properties and VAR_IN_OUT in Structured Text Object-Oriented Programming?
I am new to Object-Oriented Programming (OOP) in Structured Text (ST), but both familiar with OOP in C/C++ and ST. I would like to understand what is the difference between Properties (with a corresponding VAR to get/set) and a VAR_IN_OUT? Also, when should I use one instead of the other (in Structured Text OOP)?
Let's say that we have the abstract object "Device" that has a name:
FUNCTION_BLOCK ABSTRACT Device
VAR
    Name_ : STRING(8);
END_VAR

with the following property:
PROPERTY PUBLIC Name : STRING(8)

with the getter:
Name := Name_;

and the setter:
Name_ := Name;

What would be the difference with this:
FUNCTION_BLOCK ABSTRACT Device
VAR_IN_OUT
    Name : STRING(8);
END_VAR

In other words, when should I use the property and when should I use the VAR_IN_OUT? Similarly, when should I use a property with only a getter/setter or a VAR_OUTPUT/VAR_INPUT, respectively?

In terms of how it works no difference in according to your example. But you cannot set property during FB call.
FUNCTION_BLOCK ABSTRACT Device
VAR
    Name_ : STRING(8);
END_VAR
PROPERTY PUBLIC Name : STRING(8)

You cannot call it fbDevice(Name := "Device #1");. You can only access properties like fbDevice.Name := "Device #1";.
This means that you cannot change it during a main FB routine and apply logic to it, which depends on other VAR_INPUT parameters. I would use PROPERTY for more static variables, like configuration that is done once a PLC starts. And I would use VAR_IN_OUT for dynamic variables that can change from one FB call to another.

I think I see what you mean. However, there shouldn't be any logic inside the function block itself in OOP, just fields, properties and methods. Then, you can use the properties to get/set some fields dynamically inside a program after instantiating an object of this class (N.B. I shouldn't have made my class abstract, but you get the point), and it doesn't need to be static. I guess things are different if you use VAR_IN_OUT, where you need the FB call.

First of all, it is impossible to create FB without a logic since it is called a LOGIC BLOCK. So by definition it should contain a logic inside methods or in a block itself. Secondly, OON is not applicable to Automation programming. Some OOP features like inheritance, properties and methods are there and help to organize the code, but you cannot create PLC program with OOP paradigm.

I think you can differentiate OOP features and OOP  structure. So you can utilize inheritance but you cannot make a full OPP abstraction and structure, it is completely not suitable. Yes, OOP has become more like antipattern now a days and procedural programming is preferable. In PLC world even only right way to go. Use OOP features of Codesys to organize code but do not use OOP concept to structure your logic.
